# How to prevent dimming when playing a video?

Tags: macos, mac-mini, apple-silicon

Recently, when I'm playing a video (Youtube, DailyMotion, VLC and with each support), my external display dims immediately.

It seems to be OS-related, so I search in the various parameters, without any success.

I'm using a BenQ monitor with a brand new Mac mini M1.

Any ideas I can pursue to try to fix this?

edit : It comes from calibrated color profiles selected with my display : by changing it from Preferences, I have no problem with other profiles like Apple RGB, Display P3 etc.

Comment: What are your energy saver settings under battery preferences?

Comment: No battery, I'am using a mini. All settings in Energy saver are default ones.

Comment: Are they fullscreen or just anytime you watch one?

Comment: Anytime.

I've also tried to re-calibrate my screen, and with others color spaces. Same thing.

EDIT : ok, I found the problem. It comes from color profiles selected with my display : by changing it from Preferences, I have no problem with other profiles like Apple RGB, Display P3 etc.

Comment: What a strange and niche solution. Maybe add that as an answer, as I am sure others will come across this problem :)